# Edittext Customization : moving cursor to next & multiple part input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need my EditText like below picture where user can enter the digit and after finish the digit limit cursor will moves to next. [image]

[image]

Update: User can set date, month & year from keypad & also click and set date from DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is a [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) with the mode set to `spinner`

```
<DatePicker
    ...
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Comment: Date picker is an aditional feature .

Comment: Does that comment mean something? Is it related to "It don't know the feature name what i want"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TextWatcher class in order to get notified on change of the text within a EditText.

```
EditText mDayEditText;
EditText mMonthEditText;
EditText mYearEditText;

TextWatcher dayTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Do nothing...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() == 2) {
            mMonthEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Do nothing...
    }
};

TextWatcher monthTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Do nothing...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() == 2) {
            mYearEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Do nothing...
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

    mDayEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
    mMonthEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
    mYearEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_3);

    mDayEditText.addTextChangedListener(dayTextWatcher);
    mMonthEditText.addTextChangedListener(monthTextWatcher);
}
```

Comment: This is a simple solution if he has 3 different fields, but he's written that it's a single edit text for some reason. You could shorten it even more - give all fields the same text watcher that does ((EditText)getTag()).requestFocus(); and set the next field as each tag